# Do MvvmCross 6.4.1 packages support all versions of Visual studio?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I have updated MvvmCross packages in my application. I am getting different errors in Visual studio 2017 and Visual Studio 2019.

**In Visual Studio 2017**

> **Error CS0121:** 
>   The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'MvvmCross.Binding.BindingContext.MvxBindingContextOwnerExtensions.CreateBindingSet(TTarget)' and 'MvvmCross.Binding.BindingContext.MvxBindingContextOwnerExtensions.CreateBindingSet(TTarget)'

**In Visual Studio 2019**

> **Error XA4215:** The Java type `mvvmcross.droid.services.MvxBroadcastReceiver` is generated by more than one managed type. Please change the [Register] attribute so that the same Java type is not emitted. (XA4215)

Can anyone clarify me why is this happening?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You are probably mixing version of MvvmCross. Check your references. However, we don't officially support VS2017, we build on latest tool-chain in Azure Pipelines.

Comment: Hi @Cheesebaron,Thanks for the reply. Currently I am working in Visual Studio 2019 for Mac. I have verified my solution but didnt find any mismatch in MvvmCross packages version. I am trying to update MvvmCross.Droid packages packages from 5.7.0 to 6.4.2(latestversion) Based on the dependency added MVVMCross package and then updated those packages to 6.4.2. Still the issue Error XA4215 exists.